# How to fix height of Laravel page and carousel at loading?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, carousel

As a beginner with Php i am stuck with following issue:
During loading of my page, when graphs are not yet populated,

- Page bottom appears close to Nav bar before page resizing with graphs getting populated
- Slick-carousel briefly appears vertical before getting horizontal

This page resizing creates a poor user experience.

How can I fix page size at loading? Or should I use a spinner waiting for the full page to be ready?
Thks for advices

Update with test files to reproduce the error :

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
```

```css
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600");

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.navbar-laravel {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

// Custom
@import "custom";

// Map
@import "map";

//use also JSON wizard for formatting
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- For the coins carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header" class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="slider slider-nav">

    <!--see https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-hidden-visible-dd969a4c5854,seems not worling as nt in Grid maybe?-->
    <!-- https://www.sshakil.com/blog/article/1/Make-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic-in-Laravel-->

                   <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-0" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-1" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-2" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-3" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-4" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-5" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-6" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-7" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-8" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-9" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
                  <p>
                <img class="-logo-32x32" alt="toto-10" sizes="32x32">

          </p>
        

</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/app/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 8,
   slidesToScroll: 1,

   dots: true,
   centerMode: true,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 1000,
 });

});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have same issue with Google chart : while chart of loading their date, their placeholder is height 0 briefly before taking the expected space.
I can see on google website https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart that their chart take some time to appear but placeholder has a fix size and it is responsive.

Comment: Provide your source code, else it's a no-go.

Comment: @Rawrplus , ok, done

Comment: Could you add a background color and min-height to the div  wrapping the carousel to make it less noticeable ?

Comment: Pretty much confirmed what I suspected and @AndreiGheorgiu presumed. I feel like his answer should be enough to cover your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial, generic answer:

You're probably experiencing [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

It's because you are loading `styles` for your elements inside your `<body>` element, after the elements that are being styled have been rendered.

There are (at least) two possible fixes:

- either move the loading of your style rules inside `<head>` (and use `<link>`)
- or give your `<body>` `opacity:0; transform: opacity .5s ease-out` and after the styles have loaded change its opacity to `1`.

Obviously, the `transform` and its sub-properties are optional. If you don't want a transition you could also use `visibility` or `display` properties instead of `opacity`.

Also, instead of targeting everything (`<body>`), you could simply target the elements causing FOUC and any subsequent elements in DOM which might also be affected. To limit the unstyled elements from affecting their siblings one could use `max-height` and `min-height` on them, but keep in mind this needs to be done considering responsiveness (has to work on all device widths).

---

### Specific answer (after MCVE was added):

Looking further into the issue, it's not a classic FOUC case, but a pseudo-FOUC (styles are changed by JavaScript, when Slick is initialized). I found this [git issue](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/158),  providing multiple solutions.
Turns out placing the class `slick-slide` on each of your `<p>`'s and `slick-slider` class on the parent hides the slides before Slick is initialized, thus eliminating the pseudo-FOUC.

Alternatively, **if you don't want to add those classes** to your markup (and take advantage of Slick's existing CSS), you could add this to your own CSS:

```css
.slider p {
    display: none;
}
.slider p:first-child,
.slick-initialized.slider p {
    display: block;
}
```

...which is tailored on your current markup.

Comment: yea this corresponds to your definition of FOUC. all my css are in header...i put some code in update

Comment: @mg3, unfortunately what you added is not enough to reproduce the issue. Please open and read the provided link on what [mcve] actually means. Without the ability to reproduce your issue I can't help and chances are nobody else could. **Note:** you need to update with the parsed HTML and CSS result, not with the source code as source code is not going to work on [so]. Also make sure your example is not missing any relevant resources for the issue.

Comment: Gheorgiu...Ok include my test controller and remove of main view some unuseful js ...With the current files sent, on a blank laravel project, i managed to run it...what do you mean by parsed HTML and CSS result? The rendering given by contr+U i will suppose..

Comment: @mg3: I mean it has to work here. I push "Run example" button and I can inspect the issue. Which means instead of ` @meta` you need the actual `<meta property="some_property" content="some_content">`. I want to see what hits the browser and I'll tell you what's wrong with it. And I don't need to know what framework or language you use server side, because it doesn't matter. It's still parsed into HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You can get that from right-click > View Source. Of course, you need to comb the unnecessary. Provide minimum code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: the @meta was not useful for test so it was removed and code with control+U was provided...where is the run button that i can try on SO?

Comment: There is a `<>` button in editor. Press it and you'll know where to put your code. provide external sources from cdn's and your custom scripts just place in the appropriate panel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172891/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-mg3).